# Java Regular Expression Issue

Tags: java, xml, regex

The following exception is thrown when this `[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+(_[0-9]+){0,1}` regex is used.

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed counted closure near index 31
[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+(_[0-9]+){0
                               ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:2759)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2537)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1806)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
```

I am reading this from a XML File.

Comment: show the piece of code you use

Comment: I use Java Standard Pattern.compile and Pattern.matcher in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+(_[0-9]+)?
```

Comment: But the same pattern works in this http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: can you give some examples of what you need to match? Your supplied regex compiles fine, you may have an extra character somewhere in your string. post the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape commas with backslash:

```
[0-9]+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+(_[0-9]+){0\,1}
```

Comment: You *don't* have to escape comma's with backslash in Java regex expressions. An expression like this works: `"^(\\d+\\.){0,2}\\d+$"`. See also the discussion on [backslash, escapes and quoting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs) in the Javadoc.